# KeyError for Dandas.DataFrame.loc

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to access these two groups of columns and assign to variable x, however am running into this error. # We (temporarily) allow for some missing keys with .loc, except in KeyError: "None of [Index
dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

```
df.to_csv('Amazon1.csv',index=False)
df = pd.read_csv('Amazon1.csv')

features = [df['StarsInt'],df['Sentiment']]
x = df.loc[:,features].values

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-b8207955fac4> in <module>
----> 1 x = df.loc[:,features].values

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1759                 except (KeyError, IndexError, AttributeError):
   1760                     pass
-> 1761             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1762         else:
   1763             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   1286                 continue
   1287 
-> 1288             retval = getattr(retval, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
   1289 
   1290         return retval

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1951                     raise ValueError("Cannot index with multidimensional key")
   1952 
-> 1953                 return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)
   1954 
   1955             # nested tuple slicing

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_iterable(self, key, axis)
   1592         else:
   1593             # A collection of keys
-> 1594             keyarr, indexer = self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis, raise_missing=False)
   1595             return self.obj._reindex_with_indexers(
   1596                 {axis: [keyarr, indexer]}, copy=True, allow_dups=True

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis, raise_missing)
   1550 
   1551         self._validate_read_indexer(
-> 1552             keyarr, indexer, o._get_axis_number(axis), raise_missing=raise_missing
   1553         )
   1554         return keyarr, indexer

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
   1637             if missing == len(indexer):
   1638                 axis_name = self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)
-> 1639                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   1640 
   1641             # We (temporarily) allow for some missing keys with .loc, except in

KeyError: "None of [Index([(5, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5, 3, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, ...), (1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...)], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: `features` needs to be a list. What exactly is `features = [df['StarsInt'],df['Sentiment']]` ??

Comment: They are two columns in a df that contain integers. Would you suggest I require to pull them out or convert to a list? Thanks!